# Extracting information from a column with several values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a challenge in Excel that I have a really hard time solving. So my problem is that i am trying to write a formula so i can connect a number lets say 3040 to a cell containtin the information "3000-3091,3093-3189,3192".

As you can see the 3040 is between 3000-3091, but as i found there is no formula that i found that can actually connect these two colums (give a "True" that the number 3040 is in that cell). Do you guys have any insight in how i could maybe solve this problem?

I don't know much VBA but do you guys think it's possible to program a macro that could read a column with the values "3000-3091,3093-3189,3192"?

Using the true value as the last argument in the Vlookup function doesn't work :/

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vba
Public Function DoesValueInRange(val As Long, ranges As String) As Boolean
Dim tmp, temp
tmp = Split(ranges, ",")
For Each temp In tmp
    If InStr(temp, "-") Then
        If val >= CLng(Split(temp, "-")(0)) And val <= CLng(Split(temp, "-")(1)) Then
            DoesValueInRange = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        If val = CLng(temp) Then
            DoesValueInRange = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Usage:

1. Open VBA editor (Alt-F11)
2. Create new common module (Insert - Module)
3. Insert the code into new module
4. Close VBA editor
5. On the worksheet select some cell
6. Press <kbd>fx</kbd>
7. Select "User-defined functions" category
8. Select `DoesValueInRange` function
9. In the parameters fields

   9.1. For `Val` - the value to test or cell address which contains the value to test (for example, the value `3040`, or a cell address `$A$1` if A1 cell value is 3040)

   9.2. For `Ranges` - the string with the ranges list or cell address which contains the ranges list (for example, `3000-3091,3093-3189,3192`, or a cell address `$B$1` if B1 cell value is "3000-3091,3093-3189,3192")
10. Press OK. The function will check does the value is in one of the ranges (or equal to one of single values).

Be aware - the function does not perform its parameters correctness check.

PS. Cells addresses do not have to be absolute.